# Mean.io graphql don't allow me to insert new record in a new schema

Tags: node.js, mean-stack, graphql, mean.io

I am just a newbie in [mean.io](http://mean.io/) . I want to build an event module just like the post which can be found the default module when you make an installation. I have taken everything from the post and renamed it as event. Now when I am trying to insert a new record in the event schema its showing an error like

```
there was an error sending the query Error: GraphQL error: Unknown type "EventInput". Did you mean "PostInput"?
GraphQL error: Cannot query field "addEvent" on type "Mutation". Did you mean "addPost"?
```

So can someone tell me what I am doing wrong here? Any suggestion or help will be really appreciable.

Comment: Please avoid *"I am new to ..."*, because it doesn't help anyone to answer your question. See [Should 'Hi', 'thanks', taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950) on Meta StackExchange.

Comment: ... "the post"... can you give a link? And what modification to the code has you done? Show your code please.

Comment: when you install mean.io it creates a module posts. You can do post crud operation there. So I have just made a clone of the post and renamed it into event. The schema what I have taken is event. But it is not inserting any data into table.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with [innograph](https://github.com/linnovate/innograph).
The addPost is coming from this npm module and not the actual /server/ changes that you have made.

innograph is initialised in express.js

1. The solution is to copy the innograph code into you application. Make all the changes and actually remove innograph from package.json.
2. If its too much just remove innograph, graphql, apollo packages and then simply use express.js that is also pre-built into mean.io.

The second step requires changes to be made into /server/ folder. I had to do some debugging to actually make it work.